# Adding image to html

Tags: html

I am trying to add a gif called tenor.gif to my webpage as a joke for my instructor but it refuses to find the image I have tried using relative path and my machines path but it wont grab it. `<img src="C:\jnardone\public_html\module7\tenor.gif" alt="Trulli" width="500" height="333">` I get an error saying curly expected and selector expected from visual studio code any one have any ideas?

I have tried using everything I could.

Comment: <img src="C:\jnardone\public_html\module7\tenor.gif" alt="Trulli" width="500" height="333">

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. Can you read [ask]. The file seems not accessible, did you try to access it manually? Do you understand how it works? Don't forget the src is a web link, not a computer one

Comment: *curly expected and selector expected* - Maybe this error comes from CSS. Please share your full code

Answer (score 0):

The path is corrupted. The src provided is a desktop one. It needs to be a web one. If your html file is in public_html, just give src of src='./module7\tenor.gif'. Else, could take the gif and put it in the same file as the html file is in. Then give the path aforementioned path.

Comment: The path is "corrupted"? I don't think that's the right word choice here. That's what OP wrote and it wasn't modified by anything else.

Comment: Ok. not currupted. more like the path is wrong. Also the way op used styles is wrong. it should be like style="height:100px;width:100px;"

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `file:///`. It is called "protocol".
In your case, it will be:

```
<img src="file:///C:\jnardone\public_html\module7\tenor.gif" alt="Trulli" width="500" height="333">
```